# Something went wrong with Export to CSV using google sheet api

Tags: csv, google-sheets, export-to-csv

I'm using googlespread sheet for my app, and I have some problem when use API to export sheet to CSV.
My API I'm using: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{0}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet}](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7B0%7D/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=%7Bsheet%7D)
And my file CSV result like:

[image]

Beside my data in Google sheet like:

[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

That something went wrong, something went correct. When I got problem, I use format number to text for sheet, then it went correct, I don't know why.

Comment: About `Export to CSV using google sheet api`, in this case, can you provide your current script?